# 'asked today' shown on question 'asked 18 hours ago'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, time, date-format

While viewing a question that I asked yesterday, the **asked** day is showing as **today** as shown in the screenshot:

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832134 asked today and asked 18 hours ago highlighted]

Day is shown as **today**, the question was asked **18 hours ago** and my current time is **11.46 am**. My timezone is **UTC+5.30** (Chennai).

Comment: If I remember correctly, "today" means "within the last 24 hours" not "on this calendar day".

Comment: Its okay to show like last 24 hours as today, but how do i know its shown like that, every will stick to the calendar day.
consider the scenario happened to me, have asked the question yesterday and come back today looking for answers and it is still showing today, just confused me. thought should folowled the calendar day.

Comment: The calendar day is different for everyone. 24 hours is the same for everyone. Even if it only went by UTC, it could still be confusing for users in some time zones.

Comment: i don't  understand the part "confusing for users in some time zones". if the day is shown for the user based on his timezone then he can understand that when the question was asked. say for example if u r posting a question on some x date and that instant is x-1 date for me then if am viewing the question on my x day then it should be shown like yesterday (originally it was asked on my yesterday). i don't care about the timezone of the originator timezone, all do i care is when the question was raised in accordance with my timezone.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Nothing on this site is user-specific. All of the times on the sites... whenever you see them, they're all in UTC. The site doesn't know or care what your time zone is. When a question shows "asked Jul 17 at 9:26" that's UTC, not local time. If you hover over the word "today" of your question here, it says "6:38:01Z" - the Z means "zulu" which is the code used for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).

Comment: Okay thanks for ur information @Catija. I am unaware of "Nothing on this site is user-specific", so this is what made the confusion. 
thanks again man :)

Comment: Why not change the text to "Within the last 24h"

Comment: Because that's way too may letters @Schwertspize!